# Get label names for fields in OpenERP

Tags: python, label, odoo

How can I get label names for fields in any model?

For example writing this:

```
obj = self.read(cr,uid,ids)[0]
```

It will get dictionary of fields names (technical names, or in database column names) and their values in a given record.

So for example output would be something like this:

```
{'field1': 10, 'field2': 'hello', 'field3': 3.56}
```

But it does not return labels of fields, and I can't access it from here too, because field names here is just a string.

So let say there would be these fields mentioned above:

```
_columns = {
    'field1': fields.integer('First Field'),
    'field2': fields.char('Second Field', size=128),
    'field3': fields.float('Third Field'),
}
```

Then how could I get this instead (I know exact output is not possible, because label is not the key, but I'm just showing it to better understand the problem):

```
{'First Field': 10, 'Second Field': 'hello', 'Third Field': 3.56}
```

So I think code for retrieving labels could look something like that:

```
for k, v in obj.iteritems():
    print k.label
```

But there is no such attribute. In fields.py file I saw in most field types `string` named attribute is used as input for labels, which has default input `string='unknown'`, but I don't get it how to retrieve it while iterating over all fields in a model.

Anyone know how to do it?

P.S. Why I need this? I need to find fields whose values meet specific condition and then write that field label in other table. I could write column name, but simple users will need to see that data, so they need to understand what that field means,, thats why I need to retrieve field labels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are two tables you can use `ir.model` and `ir.model.fields`. on the second one you will get the "labels" by using the field "name".

so search for fields with a specific model get there labels. :)

for further questions just ask :)

edit: an example could be sale.order, if i want all labels for m2o relation fields with res.partner

```
...
model_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model')
imf_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.fields')
field_label_list = []
model_id = model_obj.search(cr, uid, [('model','=','sale.order')], context=context)
if model_id:
    field_ids = imf_obj.search(cr, uid, [('model_id','=',model_id[0]),('ttype','=','many2one'),('relation','=','res.partner')], context=context)
    if field_ids:
        for field in imf_obj.browse(cr, uid, field_ids, context):
            field_label_list.append(field.field_description)
#do what you want with the list
...
```

second edit: at class attribute `_columns` you will have all fields. your desired attribute for them is `string`

```
for field in self._columns.itervalues():
    print field.string
```

Comment: Can you write an example how to retrieve one label from some model using `ir.model.fields`?

Comment: Thanks. With few fixes, it works. But if other people will need something similar, it would better if you fixed errors. First one in model_id line, `]` is missing after `sale.order` domain.  Second you written `ttype`. And third, it should be field.field_description, because name return column name, not label.

Comment: Also, maybe you will know. If I need internal model id, not external (as in this example). Like if I would write method inside `sale.order`. Maybe there is simpler way to get model id from inside that model? Like it is for record where you can just browse it? P.S. right, it's `ttype`. Weird that they chose such name :)

Comment: i don't understand your question :/. but another method to get labels is in my second edit.

Comment: Second approach is way simpler. Thanks. So I don't even need model_id (which I was asking in question you said didn't understand)

Comment: oh ok, i thought i didn't understand :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hi i think in odoo version 11 its a more easier task to accomplish.

Just use

> ._fields()

and you will get the field labels.

You can find more useful function by using dir() in odoo console.

Hope that will help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
self.fields_get('fieldname')
```

Example:

```
self.fields_get('phonenumber')
```

Output will be:

```
{'phonenumber': {'change_default': False, 'string': u'Phone', 'searchable': True, 'required': False, 'manual': False, 'readonly': False, 'depends': (), 'company_dependent': False, 'sortable': True, 'translate': False, 'type': 'Float', 'store': True}}
```